# Managing network storage from terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, mount, ftp, gvfs

Sorry for the question that is too general, but I would like to switch to using the terminal instead of GUI programs as much as possible and I cannot formulate my question more precisely.

In the course of my work, I need to connect to multiple FTP directories and Samba shared drives and also for MTP (smartphone) drives at home. I want to join them in the same way so I can handle them as uniformly as possible.

Currently, GIO Virtual Filesystem / GVFS seems to be the best solution because I can log in to the drives in a similar way (`gio mount`) and access them via a similar path (`/run/user/1000/gvfs/...`). The problem is that this solution seems to be optimized for GUI because e.g. I can't copy to MTP (smartphone) drives, only from the GUI, but the GUI also uses GVFS.

Is there a proven way to connect to different (network) drives from a terminal as easily as from a GUI?

Comment: What's wrong with autofs?

Comment: Are you looking for some piece of _zero-configuration_ CLI software that allows you to perform the same operations as a rich GUI file manager? (Just trying to make sure I'm understanding your question correctly).

Comment: @JiriB, didn't know `autofs`, I will look for it.

@fra-san, I'm pretty much thinking of such a solution, `gio mount` works in a similar way. In fact, the goal is to be able to easily manage drives. It doesn't matter if I have to write to a config file. I'm really curious how others doing remote file handling in a terminal.